# requesting a domain but going to another host

Tags: networking, dns

so i am in a place where i have access to only 5 websites and i am trying to bypass this restrection

when i try to browse any of those website i don't have any problem, for example stackoverflow.com , but i can't access 1.1.1.1 (which is the ip of stackoverflow) 
it means that what ever is blocking the other website allow only those 5 domains 
is there anyway i can sumbit a web request to 2.2.2.2 but in the headers i am requesting stackoverflow.com to bypass this restrection

i have no idea how does dns or a simple http request work , i aperciate any idea to start with or at least something to read

also i can't change my dns servers

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting

Comment: Then what don't you understand?

Comment: can i submit a request like this 

GET 1.1.1.1/index.html HTTP/1.1

Host: www.example.com

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to make your own http implementation. Plus, the server will only accept your request if it ignores the `Host` header, as many servers use it for virtual hosting.

Comment: of course, i don't care about the host, the server will be my own server i'll use it as proxy later
the question if is it possible, how should the header look like ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with any telnet application:

`telnet google.com 80`

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

End your request with double enter.

If you receive html then the proxy is letting the request pass.

Comment: this is intresting,the proxy allow only port 80 requests(i tried https didn't work)

i will try it and get back to you 

thanks man

Comment: Does your browser have a http proxy configured? This will work if the filter is in your default gateway, if you have a http proxy you need to open the connection to your proxy and it will redirect the request to the `host`, so you have no work around there.

Comment: I don't think you can establish an https connection with telnet.