# VPN connection with fixed headers

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

This is a follow up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232390/requesting-a-domain-but-going-to-another-host/22233961?noredirect=1#comment33794063_22233961).

I don't know the website policy about posting a new question based on an old one, I hope that I am not doing anything wrong.

But there is some new updates:

> 1 - I discovered that I can change my DNS server and it will work
>   perfectly (I didn't find a way to use that for my advantage yet)
>
> 2 - I am capable now of browsing any website I can using tamper data
>   (firefox addon) I simply get the website ip, request it in the browser
>   and then i change the host to one of the allowed websites domain and
>   it work perfectly, but that doesn't mean that I can browse normally
>   because there is still images,css,js files don't load because I have
>   to do the same thing with every request.
>
> 3 - I read about tunneling IP traffic over DNS and icmp and tried
>   that too, the first one  worked, I was able to connect but I couldn't
>   do anything with it because simply the internet speed is very slow
>   using ip over dns, and the second didn't work at all because I can't
>   ping anything.

Now I am little bit confused, I am looking for a proxy or a VPN that I can setup on a server to work with my internet connection,a program that change every request from my computer to the vpn server by adding only the host header with one of the allowed websites so the request can be passed to the vpn server.

I don't even know how to google that!